# Update Custom field in Standrad object (opportunity) based on the custom field in custom object (Project)

Tags: workflow, process-builder

I have a custom object (*Project*) that has a custom field *Project Registration payment*, which is manually entered when the registration payment is done by the owner.

**My requirement:** Once the *registration payment* field in the *Project* is updated, the *Registration payment status* (custom field - yes/no) in the related opportunities should be updated automatically.

Comment: you could try to implement with process builder

Comment: how to use process builder?

Comment: refer this trailhead (Automate Basic Business Processes with Process Builder) https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/business_process_automation/units/process_builder